# C# Looking for code friendlier solution to implementing inherited generic typed event delegates from interface

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, properties, delegates

I'm looking for another way to solve this issue I stumbled on.

> Error CS0738 'MyImplementationClass' does not implement interface member 'IMyAbstractClass< IMyType >.MyEvent'. 'MyAbstractClass< MyType >.MyEvent' cannot implement 'IMyAbstractClass< IMyType >.MyEvent' because it does not have the matching return type of 'MyDelegate< IMyType >'

I'm working on a project which requires me to create an interfaces assembly to allow another team to do their work without knowing the implementation of said interfaces.

So I created a "Project.Interfaces" assembly where I declared all my public interfaces. And an "Project.Implementation" assembly where I declared all my internal classes. Each class/struct implementing it's own interface, which inherits from a base interface wherever the class inherits from a base class too.

I needed to declare an event in one of the classes, using a constrained type parameter. This class is abstract, and an specialized implementation class exists.

Here is an example of the code which allows to reproduce the issue. I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.2:

```
public interface IMyDataType
{ 
}

internal class MyDataTypeClass : IMyDataType
{
}

public delegate void MyDelegate<MyDataType>(MyDataType argument)
    where MyDataType : IMyDataType;

public interface IMyAbstractClass<MyDataType>
    where MyDataType : IMyDataType
{
    event MyDelegate<MyDataType> MyEvent;
}

internal abstract class MyAbstractClass<MyDataType> : IMyAbstractClass<MyDataType>
    where MyDataType : IMyDataType
{
    public event MyDelegate<MyDataType> MyEvent;
}

public interface IMyImplementationClass : IMyAbstractClass<IMyDataType>
{
}

internal class MyImplementationClass : MyAbstractClass<MyDataTypeClass>, IMyImplementationClass
{
}
```

This also happens if the member is a property of MyDataType type, instead of a delegate.

I understand the cause of the compiler error, MyDelegate< IMyDataType > can't be casted as MyDelegate< MyDataTypeClass >.

But MyDataTypeClass IS an implementation of IMyDataType. So calling a method which receives a parameter of IMyDataType, passing a MyDataTypeClass typed object/struct is possible.

In order to work around this, I had to reimplement the "MyEvent" member in the implementation class, as an explicit implementation of the interfaces' member, and chaining the original event, which requires cleanup of the chaining event.

```
internal class MyImplementationClass : MyAbstractClass<MyDataTypeClass>, IMyImplementationClass
{
    event MyDelegate<IMyDataType> IMyAbstractClass<IMyDataType>.MyEvent
    {
        add
        {
            var chainedEvent = new MyDelegate<MyDataTypeClass>(value);
            chainedEvents.Add(value, chainedEvent);
            base.MyEvent += chainedEvent;
        }

        remove
        {
            if (chainedEvents.ContainsKey(value))
            {
                var chainedEvent = chainedEvents[value];
                chainedEvents.Remove(value);
                base.MyEvent -= chainedEvent;
            }
        }
    }

    private IDictionary<MyDelegate<IMyDataType>, MyDelegate<MyDataTypeClass>> chainedEvents =
                new Dictionary<MyDelegate<IMyDataType>, MyDelegate<MyDataTypeClass>>();
}
```

For properties, a similar re implementation chaining the original property is required. Tough a simple implicit cast suffices, and no clean up is needed.

I have two problems with this solution:

1. I don't know  why, but it doesn't work when using value referenced types for the < MyDataType > parameter. e.g: internal struct MyDataTypeStruct : IMyDataType

   > Error CS0123 No overload for 'MyDelegate< IMyDataType >.Invoke(IMyDataType)' matches delegate 'MyDelegate< MyDataTypeStruct >'
2. My real world implementation class inherits twice from the original abstract class (abstract -> slightly more specialized abstract -> specialized class). So I had to repeat the exact same chaining of the event in both the middle class and final class.

Already tried and no-go solutions:

1. Moving the event to the final implementation classes' interface, because the other team requires to know the event from the basemost abstract
   classes' interface.
2. Changing the final clases' interface to IMyAbstractClass< MyDataTypeClass/MyDataTypeStruct > instead of IMyAbstractClass< IMyDataType >, because it causes an "Inconsistent accessibility", forcing me to make the class/struct public and delivering the "Project.Implementation" assembly to the other team which is not the intended purpose. It would also force me to implement the event (though self implementation is possible) in every sibling class.

So, does anyone know of a code friendlier way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach of publishing the `IMyImplementationClass` as generic was also a no go. It forced me to make the data type public.

As StriplingWarrior said, there was no real need for the delegate to have a typed parameter. So I just declared it as `public delegate void MyDelegate(IMyDataType argument)` and that avoided the need to chain the event in every inheriting class.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

How about making `IMyImplementationClass` generic?

```
public interface IMyImplementationClass<MyDataType> : IMyAbstractClass<MyDataType>
    where MyDataType : IMyDataType
{
}

internal class MyImplementationClass : MyAbstractClass<MyDataTypeClass>, IMyImplementationClass<MyDataTypeClass>
{
}
```

Comment: Insteresting, I will be testing this tomorrow. A problem with this does comes into mind. How would I go about returning the IMyImplementationClass< MyDataTypeClass > ? without making MyDataTypeClass public and delivering the implementation assembly.

AFAIK You can't have a method return a generic interface without defining the typed parameter. Either explicitly or implicitly thruought a method argument.

Comment: @podostro: How do you intend to use the returned `IMyImplementationClass` in the consuming code? If you don't have access to `MyDataTypeClass`, how do you intend to subscribe to an event that passes that specific class in as a parameter? If the consuming code only cares about the argument being an `IMyDataType`, then why is that delegate generic in the first place? Why not just have your delegate use a non-generic `IMyDataType` argument? It's hard to help you much without a better understanding of what you're hoping to accomplish.